# ruby on rails save group of checkboxes collection select check box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Good Day

i have model 
Food
Dayoffer

Food which is records with all foods   in our canteen

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :supplier
 has_many :dayoffer
end
```

Dailyoffer is restricted set of foods which are offered on some day.

```
class Dayoffer < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :food
end
```

i dont know how to effectively save choices for day 
i have idea to use in form collection_check_boxes but dont know how to process it  effectively.

schema of db on 
https://gist.github.com/netmoleCBA/089950c54a4b8e066da8afc54fa5a62e

Comment: What are the associations between models? Show us the code

Comment: attached Gist updated  but fastly  food has_many dayoffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a WeekDay model that has many offers and seed seven week days in your database :

in your food form:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:week_day_ids, WeekDay.all, :id, :name) do |week_day| %>
  <%= week_day.label { week_day.check_box } %>
<% end %>
```

D'ont forget to add week_day_ids in the controller's strong params

```
params.require(:food).permit(:name, week_day_ids:[])
```

Comment: yes but how given set save  in db as i dont have one master key as it is set of records with have same date so question is if i shall move date field from day offer to day model and make   model day has many dayoffer